# How many games will a “MENACE” tic tac toe computer take to train

Tags: machine-learning

I recently read about the “computer” built out of matchboxes designed by Donald Michie that could teach itself how to play tic tac toe. Here is the Wikipedia article about it:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_Educable_Noughts_and_Crosses_Engine

I thought it looked interesting, so I decided to make a digital version in Python for fun and practice. It works well against random moves (I just ran it again for 5353 games on the data generated by ≈10,000 games and it won 4757 out of 5353) but it still looses often against me.

Here are some points that a perfect answer would address:

- How many games will it take for a “matchbox computer” that works exactly like the one Michie designed to start playing perfectly?
- Did the original computer with actual matchboxes ever reach perfect
  play?
- Will the computer ever reach perfect play if trained against    only
  random moves?

EDIT:
This question is not asking for help with the code, but a comment below suggested that including the code could be a help. Here is a link to a GitHub repository I created so I could share it here:

https://github.com/ACertainArchangel/Recreation-Of-MENACE-Tic-Tac-Toe..git

Sorry, I know it's not very good and doesn't obey conventions; I've only been coding a couple of months :)

Comment: I doubt you'll find anyone old enough who can speak up about the exact MENACE performance, or anyone who attempted to implement it. However on wiki there is an image, that after 150 games the first move becomes optimal, so I would guess that 10000 games would be fairly enough to win games somewhat consistently

Comment: You better show your code an maybe the error will be more clear

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. I have added a link to a GitHub repository as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got my answer to this question from a user named "Tassle" from computer science stack exchange; here is a link to his answer:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/167260/how-many-games-will-a-menace-tic-tac-toe-computer-take-to-train?noredirect=1#comment346349_167260

In short, Tassle says that the computer will get "stuck" choosing one set of opening moves over and over even if it is not optimal — if it performs well against random moves, which it likely will. Tassle explains it much better than I could.

After getting my answer I tried training the AI against another copy of itself, and this produced slightly better results. Then I tried swapping between AI and random for a lot of games to see if perhaps the AI would find ways to exploit weaknesses developed by random training, and then random training could "shake things up" again. The difference was immediately apparent (it now only looses once in a blue moon).

Increasing the number of beads taken from the matchbox on a loss (and making sure the total wouldn't fall below zero) also helped. I am now happy with how it is working.